# iPhone -- working with complex numbers

Tags: iphone, complex-numbers

I'm trying to figure out the best way to put complex numbers into my math-oriented iPhone app.  I've found the [mac osx manual page for complex numbers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/complex.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/complex), which looks like a reasonable start.  Three questions:

(1)  Is this the best starting point?
(2)  I will need an object-oriented wrapper -- can NSValue do this somehow?  Or should I just write my own?  (not difficult, but I'd rather use a built-in one if it exists).
(3)  Is there a built-in way to get a string representation of a complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seems reasonable.
2. I would just create a class of your own which has a complex ivar.  It might be possible to subclass NSNumber (and thus NSValue) to do something sane, but you'll have to be a bit careful.
3. No, just get the real and imaginary parts and print those.

Comment: I'm likely to accept this unless someone comes up with something better in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no built-in complex number support in Cocoa (other than the C libraries).  It sounds like you have a good approach.  I haven't looked at it carefully yet, but [here's a cocoa calculator with source code](http://projectswithlove.com/magicnumbermachine/) that supports complex numbers--you might be able to get some ideas.

Comment: I'm upvoting this cos that's a cool little calc.  But he implemented complex numbers from scratch.  This gave him arbitrary precision, but it's a lot more work than I'm willing to do.