# iOS -- implementing complex numbers

Tags: iphone, ios, math, rounding, complex-numbers

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340219/iphone-working-with-complex-numbers):

I was in the process of implementing a calculator app using [Apple's complex number support](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/complex.3.html) when I noticed that if one calculates using that support, one ends up with the following:

(1+i)^2=1.2246063538223773e-16 + 2i

Of course the correct identity is (1+i)^2=2i.  This is a specific example of a more general phenomenon -- roundoff errors can be really annoying if they round a part that is supposed to be zero to something that is slightly nonzero.

Suggestions on how to deal with this?  I could implement integer powers of complex numbers in other ways, but the general problem will remain, and my solution could itself cause other inconsistencies.

Comment: I think in a calculator app it is appropriate to round both real and imaginary part (e.g. to 12 decimal digits) before displaying the result.

Answer (score 3):

As you note, this is as standard rounding error issue with floating points. A @Howard notes, you should likely round your double results back into the float range before displaying.

I typically use `FLT_EPSILON` to help me with these kinds of things as well.

```
#define fequal(a,b) (fabs((a) - (b)) < FLT_EPSILON)
#define fequalzero(a) (fabs(a) < FLT_EPSILON)
```

With those, you might like a function like this (untested)

```
inline void froundzero(a) { if (fequalzero(a)) a = 0; }
```

The complex version is left as an exercise for the reader as they say :D